# APNS multiple registerId's

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My App is using APNS push. Now I read that you can leave the connection open while sending multiple messages. So reason enough for me to change some scripts.

My APNS class has the following methods(and many more, but these are the most important for now):

```
public function setRegisterId($registerId){
    $this->registerId = $registerId;
}

public function setupConnection()
{
    $APNSdetails[1] = array('pemFile'=>'test.pem', 'passPhrase'=>'passPhrase');
    $APNSdetails[2] = array('pemFile'=>'mag.pem', 'passPhrase'=>'passPhrase');

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/as/'.$APNSdetails[$this->appId]['pemFile']);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $APNSdetails[$this->appId]['passPhrase']);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $this->connection = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$this->connection){
        return FALSE;
    }
    else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}

public function sendMessage()
{
    $RegisterIds = $this->registerId;
    foreach ($RegisterIds AS $key => $value){

        // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $RegisterIds[$key]['registerId']) . pack('n', strlen($this->payload)) . $this->payload;

        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($this->connection, $msg, strlen($msg));

        $RegisterIds[$key]['payload'] = $this->payload;

        if (!$result){
            $RegisterIds[$key]['result'] = 'Message not delivered';
        }
        else{
            $RegisterIds[$key]['result'] = 'Message successfully delivered';
        }
    }

    $this->results = $RegisterIds;
}
```

Now I'm testing the script with some user typed data: (i've removed last 6 characters of registerId, for safety purposes). Using this array, both devices are receiving the Push Message.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [registerId] => ddbb8b9b27beed70e56866d07a3da5f4cabf71ffab4606967a523e93eb
            [id] => 214
            [deviceOs] => apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [registerId] => c20f10e0b7f345988440d860bfb179f5b95a47d7eee714f5e0268c2c93
            [id] => 234
            [deviceOs] => apple
        )

)
```

Using a query to retrieve other (more real live) data provided with the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [registerId] => 165ad6daa6e6e2c470d1c2777901e731f34fbe419f7d93cda383665c39
            [id] => 1111
            [deviceOS] => apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [registerId] => ddbb8b9b27beed70e56866d07a3da5f4cabf71ffab4606967a523e93eb
            [id] => 1328
            [deviceOS] => apple
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [registerId] => 7383d29d4bc210b32ea409e46a99ca522a3cf4a51e330f7d7457f7bc88
            [id] => 359
            [deviceOS] => apple
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [registerId] => c20f10e0b7f345988440d860bfb179f5b95a47d7eee714f5e0268c2c93
            [id] => 1148
            [deviceOS] => apple
        )

)
```

As you can see that are 2 the same registerId's and 2 new registerId's. However, none of the 4 devices is receiving a push notification.

I'm, kind of stuck or lost... Why is the second array failing?

Comment: Are you querying the [feedback service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)? It's possible that one of the other 2 push tokens has expired.

Comment: Yes i do, no failures. But it the other two have been expired, the 2 existing should receive the Push Notification or not?

Comment: If you don't bail out or anything if one fails then yes the others should receive the push. Have you checked to see if push is definitely enabled on the devices for your app? Push notifications are not always guaranteed so there is always a chance that you could get some undelivered notifications.

Comment: Hi james, yes i did. I made two scripts 1 with the user defined array and the second with the queried array. User-defined is always working, Queried-defined is always failing.

Comment: Then it's most likely an issue with your queried array, it's difficult to see what the difference is with your code sample, is it possible you could be storing the tokens incorrectly? e.g. are they being truncated, unexpected char etc.?

Comment: Strange, var_dump says both array's use string(64) for registerId.

Comment: The User-defined  $result returns 145 and the query defined  $result returns 148. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: **UPDATE** Directly accessing a correct a working RegisterId from the DB works, but the others doesn't.

Comment: `$result` would be the number of bytes written via `fwrite` so clearly there is an issue here because the queried array should return almost double that number...seems like you are only sending part of the data to the server.

Comment: The difference between the 2 might be because of difference in message, _1 added to the database. In order to distinguish them.

Comment: Yeah actually that makes sense, I forgot this is *per message* and not the *total* messages. Can you show me an example of the payload you are sending? Remember payloads must be within a maximum size.

Comment: User-defined: {"aps":{"alert":"A new order has been placed (APNS v2)","badge":"1","sound":"default"},"e":"order","i":"12"} Query-defined: {"aps":{"alert":"A new ticket has been placed (APNS v2_1)","badge":"1","sound":"default"},"e":"order","i":"12"}

Comment: Well that rules out the payload size, the only thing I can think of is your `$msg` is corrupt somehow when it's queried. Just double check the formatting & content of the data (make sure nothings encoded incorrectly etc.). I think there is something wrong in there.

Comment: Stange thing the `$msg` is exactly the same (if both messages are the same). I'm totally lost, data that goes into msg is the same, even the types.

Comment: Your *certain* of that? Because clearly it's the only difference between both scripts. Are you sure when it's being pulled from the DB there isn't any extra whitespace or anything on the token? For example, are you storing the token as `nchar` or `varchar`?

Comment: Yes, i'm certain of that. Because when quering the existing working registerid directly, and only using that one. It works.

Comment: I've added the Apple response feature (fread).   $apple_error_response = fread($this->connection, 6); 
  var_dump($apple_error_response);
However, it returns nothing..

Comment: **Update** When using a different ORDER BY, lastUsed (defines when the device is lastRegistered to the server). It works for the last used devices. However, other devices it doesn't. Strange...

Comment: Anything in particular about these devices which aren't working?

Comment: Not that I know. Strange... Really strange this. Because the failing registerId's aren't appearing in the feedback service.

Comment: Is this intermittent or is it always those devices failing?

Comment: For now it is only these. We haven't tested it with others. Actually it is hard to chase... As we get a succes response for all devices.

Comment: If you get a success from the server and no notification from the feedback response then the only thing I can think of is the APNS server is deliberately not sending push notifications for those devices. It is stated that devices can be blocked of Apple detects misuse, if you are using those devices for testing you should be using the test server and not the live.

Comment: That can be the case. However, does apple close the connection after 1 message is pushed to that registerId? Because it does not clarify why the 'working' registerId's are not pushed then?

Comment: Are you registering to the push notification service *everytime* your app runs? It's possible that the devices themselves are failing to connect to the APNS service or they are sending stale tokens to the server, try completely killing & re-launching the app on the affected devices. Have a look at the [help docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that the first device token you send the message to (`165ad6daa6e6e2c470d1c2777901e731f34fbe419f7d93cda383665c39`) is invalid. When Apple gets this token, they close the connection. Your code sends the following 3 notifications before realizing the connection was dropped, and that's why none of them are sent.

As for not getting any error response from Apple, you are sending the notifications in the old format (the one in which the first byte is `0`). In order to be able to get error responses, you must use one of the newer formats (those that begin with `1` or `2` and contain a message ID).

Comment: Hi eran, thanks for your explanation, will that resolve the connection problem as well? Or will it always close the connection if 1 device token is incorrect?

Comment: @PeterFox It will always close the connection when it encounters an invalid device token.

Comment: @PeterFox - can you share your code for how you resolve this issue?  Im facing the same / similar issue and sort of stuck at the moment.